# PHP $_SESSION Not checking login status

Tags: php, session

I've looked through multiple web articles and stackoverflow answers, however I cannot find the bug in my code. Maybe I've been looking at it too long.

Basically I'm just setting up a simple login for a demonstration, yes I know its inject-able and outdated, this doesn't matter. Basically I'm using a login with sessions and then redirecting the user to secure content when they're logged in. I've also created a script that checks for the session variables, to see if the user is logged in or not. Basically, I'm beating a dead horse and I don't know why this isn't working, could someone please help?

index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome, please log in</title>
<link href="../css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <?PHP require_once"scripts/mysql_connect.php"; // Establish a database connection ?>

    <div id="admin_top">
        <div id="admin_logo"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="admin_login_box">
        <H1 style="margin-left: 20px;">Please log in</H1>
        <hr><br>

        <?PHP

        echo "<form method='post' action='checklogin.php' name='loginform'>

        <input type='email' name='aEmail' placeholder='Your Email Address' required><br>
        <input type='password' name='aPassword' placeholder='Password' required><br><br>
        <input type='submit' value='Log In'>

    </form>"

    ?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

checklogin.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Checking login...</title>
<link href="../css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="admin_top">
        <div id="admin_logo"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="admin_login_box">

        <?php 
              require_once"scripts/mysql_connect.php"; 

                $aEmail = $_POST['aEmail'];
                $aPassword = $_POST['aPassword']; 
                $md5Password = MD5($aPassword);

                $sql = "SQL";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $active = $row['active'];

                $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

                // If result matched, table row must be 1 row.

                if($count == 1) {
                     $_SESSION["login"] = "OK";
                     $_SESSION["aEmail"] = $aEmail;
                     echo "<h1>Log in successfull!</h1>
                            <hr><br />
                            Your details checked out! Redirecting you now...";
                     // Wait 1 seconds then redirect to the secure content.
                     header("Location: http://www.website.com/secure_content.php");                  
                } else {
                    echo "<h1>Log in unsuccessfull!</h1>
                            <hr><br />
                            Sorry. It seems your log in detials were incorrect. Please go back and try again.";
                    // Wait 2 seconds then redirect back to the log in page.
                    header("Location: http://www.website.com/index.php");
                }
                exit;
        ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

loginstatus.php:

```
<?php session_start();
    if(!(isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] == "OK")) {
        header("Location: http://www.website.com/index.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: session_start should go on top of every script you use and not only loginstatus.php

Comment: add `session_start();` on each page `(.php)` on top

Comment: You can't use `header("Location: ...)` after you've written something in the output. Move your check at the top of the page before your `<!doctype html>`

Answer (score 2):

In `checklogin.php` and `index.php` you need to start the session. Add the following code before `<!doctype html>`

Add this code:

`<?php session_start(); ?>`

You forgot to put that line in this file because you are creating a new session during the checks in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't started the session in the first place. On the top of your page please write the following code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Now, secondly, I'd suggest you to write your HTML and PHP separately instead of writing your HTML for the form within the echo.

Also, it's better if you add a name to your submit button.

Let me show a sample below.

```
<div id="admin_login_box">
    <H1 style="margin-left: 20px;">Please log in</H1>
    <hr><br>

    <form method='POST' action='checklogin.php' name='loginform'>

        <input type='email' name='aEmail' placeholder='Your Email Address' required><br>
        <input type='password' name='aPassword' placeholder='Password' required><br><br>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Log In'>

    </form>
```

Now, in your checklogin.php. you should place an isset condition and see if you're getting any POST request.

Try this:

```
<?php 
   require_once"scripts/mysql_connect.php"; 

   if (isset($_POST['submit']) {           // Add this condition

       $aEmail = $_POST['aEmail'];
       $aPassword = $_POST['aPassword']; 
       $md5Password = MD5($aPassword);

       /* Other code */

       if($count == 1) {
          /* Other code */
       } else {
         /* Other code */
       }
   }
```

Hope this helps.